# How can one get rid of a subconsciously persistent belief?

Tags: emotion, rationality

How can someone get rid of a belief that he thinks is not true, but at the same time he still suffers guilt whenever he is not acting in accord with that belief?

Here's an example that I made up to explain what I mean:

Imagine a child that was raised on the fact that he was not allowed to make loud noises by either turning the TV volume too loud or by any other means, otherwise the neighbors in the apartment building might complain and call the police. Let's say that he's now a grown man who lives in a large house on a large piece of land, however, he still experiences guilt whenever he makes any loud noise. He is fully conscious of the fact that his guilt is irrational and there is no problem with making a loud noise.